# onmousemove event and closure javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I don't know how to explain so I'll start by showing my code.
So I have something like that:

```
//array of all div's positions 
var zone = [];

//add a div's position in the array
function myFunction1(){
  var pos = getPos(div);
  zone[zone.length] = pos;
}

//when the mouse isn't in the zone of a div, delete all zones
function myEventFunction(e){
  var posMouse = xx; //define the pos of the mouse
  for(i=0: i<zone.length; i++){
    if(posMouse !== zone[i]){
      zone = [];
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, it's just a simplified version of my code.

functions works but there's a problem of "timing".
when my mouse leave the zone, it immediately enter on another div that start "myFunction1".
the function "myEventFunction" doesn't have the time to delete all data in zone[], because there's new datas in zone[] so "if(posMouse !== zone[i])" is false instead of being true.

I think i need to use closure, but i don't know how to do that.
I'm not sure if my question is understandable enough, but may someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look into the `onmouseleave` event instead of `onmousemove`, that will only fire once when you're going between divs.

Comment: The problem is that i add more than one div in zone. so i can leave a div but not leaving a zone.
"myFunction1" start when onmouseover on a div. and this div has 2-8 other div that should add position in zone[].
When i leave one of all that div, then it should delete them from zone[].
Understand? my english is a little bad...